# QNAP Container Station - Multiple dockers get Permission Denied

Tags: docker, permissions, containers, nas, qnap

I run a QNAP TS-453a at home running Container Station on it. Suddenly multiple containers got some sort of error about "Permission Denied".
For example postgres\postgres returns:
`error: exec failed: permission denied`
nodered/node-red docker returns: `exec ./entrypoint.sh: permission denied`. And this continues in different forms for a total of 20 containers. Basically every container returns permission errors on the docker-entrypoint. I shared my docker.sock with 3 containers to maintain it: HomeAssistant, WatchTower and Portainer.

What I tried:

- Recreate the container from scratch
- Checked the permissions on the shared volumes
- Reinstalled Container Station/Docker
- Restart the QNAP NAS
- `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Same problem here... did you find the solution?

Comment: I ended up rebuilding my containers from scratch...

Comment: Thanks for responsing, what exactly have you done and how? My Qnap kowledge is very limited... I understand that it is something else than "Reinstalled Container Station/Docker". Maybe you can make it into answer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.
After upgrade QTS the majority of my container as a `error: exec failed: permission denied`.
After investigation, it affects only containers that change user on their scripts.
I have found that the base image on the QTS container station was the issue.
I remove the container and the associate image and renew the container and repull a new image and the problem has gone.
I think that Container station has affected the pull image because the permission on files on a fresh container was not the same after repull a new image.